# Index out of range, error

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

my code sometimes throw error but sometimes not.

Error:
Index out of range.

code:

```
 protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();

        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RecievingDate", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FromMobileNo", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsComplaint", typeof(short)));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
            ManageRecievedMessage mngRecMsg = new ManageRecievedMessage();
            DropDownList IsValid = (DropDownList) GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlValidity");
            short IsComplaint;

            if (IsValid.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                IsComplaint= Convert.ToInt16(IsValid.SelectedValue.ToString());
                mngRecMsg.UpdateSmsComplaintValidity(ID, 1);

                DataRow datarw = null;
                datarw = dtRoom.NewRow();

                    datarw[0] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
                    datarw[1] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                    datarw[2] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                    datarw[3] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                    datarw[4] = IsComplaint; //Convert.ToInt16(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);

                dtRoom.Rows.Add(datarw);
            }
            else if(IsValid.SelectedValue != "1" )
            {       
                    IsComplaint= Convert.ToInt16(IsValid.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    mngRecMsg.UpdateSmsComplaintValidity(ID, IsComplaint);
            }
        }

        GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report_SmsComplaintsByDate.rdlc");

        if (dtRoom.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NotExists";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
            ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ReportDataSource rpds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtRoom);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpds);
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

at this line:

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
```

my gridview is displaying two rows, among whihc i have to validate whether VALID (1) or invalid (0) from dropdown but it throws error but sometimes it doesn't.

ERROR:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}
```

Comment: Change I<=4. May be Your grid view doesn't have more than 5 rows

Comment: Do you know in what situation you get that error (can you repeat it?). What is different from the non-error situation? Fire up the debugger and step through the code in the error situation. Inspect the various (sub)lists: does the indexed item exist? Why not? Then decide how to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid doesn't always have **at least** 5 rows so trying to index into the `Rows` collection causes your out of bounds exception. Looks a little odd to me that you're currently exepcting exactly 5 rows but if you're getting this error it is not the case.

To avoid the error change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
    ....
```

Comment: Are you certain that's the line causing exception? There's a lot of explicit indexing in that code which can be dangerous..

Comment: and by the way what explicit indexing ? e.g. ?

Comment: eg. `Cells[0]` or `Rows[i]` - Without bounds checking this will cause index out of bounds exceptions if the collection doesn't contain an element at the specified index.

Comment: If you're certain it's that line, then your `Cells` collection must be null/empty. Whereby `Cells[0]` is causing the exception

Comment: so what should i do ? how to avoid it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57394/discussion-between-chris-l-and-user3518032).

Comment: Note that the `i <= ...Count` check will access 1 row *more* than there are. You need `i < ...Count`.

Comment: Yes - typo :) I've changed it